# SQL Server database - row-level update datetime stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to figure out the best approach to updating a `DateLastModified` column when records are updated. Let's say we have a table called `Attribute` that has the following columns:

```
Id, ProductId, Key, Value, DateAdded, DateLastModified
```

We want to update `DateLastModified` whenever the `Key` or `Value` columns (or any column in the row) are updated; but we only want to update `DateLastModified` when a value has truly changed; not just when an update query is run against the row that has the same data.

Is there a preferred way to do this at the database level in SQL, like in a trigger? What about performance concerns? This would be in SQL Server 2019 Express edition.

To take it a step further, if we also have a `Product` table that is the PK to the FK in the `Attribute` table, and we want to update the `DateLastModified` in the `Product` row at the same time the `Attribute.DateLastModified` is updated, is that also possible in a trigger?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL 2019 Express Edition; new database design and setup

Comment: Trigger will be the ideal solution. I believe the datamodel is to support an OLTP system and DMLs are transactional in nature and there are not bulk operations being performed on the tables.If so performance has to be evaluated as trigger will be bottleneck depending on volume of data. If you have a control on the UI, suggestion would be to check if a record has been changed before making the changes.Force the user only when a record is really modified.

Comment: To give a little more context, this is more of a data warehouse that have bulk inserts/updates/selects, as well as individual record updates through a web-based UI.  We'll have control over the UI; just investigating options for bulk updates.  We could add logic at the data access layer that checks for this and performs an additional update to these fields; I was just curious of a server side solution existed.